# Load map markers from server with limit and offset

Tags: java, android, google-maps, limit, offset

I am showing markers in a radius, based on user's current location and I would like to load a preset number of markers from the server when I start activity with my maps fragment, and load more as needed - ideally load 20 markers/locations when the app starts, then on user's command load 20 by 20 more. This should be done instead of returning all locations from server which could potentially really slow down the app.

**I thought of using marker clustering, or call the method when user swipes or clicks on the map, but I am not sure if that is ideal solution.**

In lists I can do that easily using something like this `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()`:

```
listView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        int visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int pastVisibleItems = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if (pastVisibleItems + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
                //End of list
                fetchAllLocations(locationForDate, latitude, longitude);
            }
        }
});
```

The example above is pretty straight forward - I get to the bottom of the list and the method  is called again, and it returns more locations.

I was not able to find any standardized way to call the load more method for map markers.

I would use `LocationListSize` to keep number of returned locations, and use that in map method that returns locations:

```
void fetchAllLocations(String LocationForDate, String latitude, String longitude) {
    TokenManager tokenManager = TokenManager.getInstance(getContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE));
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.createServiceWithAuth(ApiInterface.class, tokenManager);
    CallLocationsFromSQLite(LocationForDate);

    SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> settings = db.getSettings();
    String radius, receiveFrom;
    radius = settings.get("radius");
    receiveFrom = settings.get("invites_received_from");

    LocationListSize = LocationList.size();
    String offset = String.valueOf(LocationListSize);
    String count = String.valueOf(20);

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Call<LocationsResponse> call = apiService.getLocationsForConditions(LocationForDate, radius, latitude, longitude, receiveFrom, count, offset);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LocationsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LocationsResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<LocationsResponse> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Location> Locations = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getResults();

                    if (Locations != null) {
                        for (Location Location : Locations) {
                            setMarker(Double.parseDouble(Location.getLat()), Double.parseDouble(Location.getLon()),
                                    Location.getId(), Location.getUserName(), Location.getDateTime());
                        }
                        // Adding number of locations retrieved to current count
                        Integer numberOfOhterLocations = Locations.size();
                        LocationListSize += numberOfOhterLocations;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (response.code() == 401) {

                        ApiError apiError = ErrorUtils.converErrors(response.errorBody());
                        Log.d(TAG, "There was an error: " + apiError);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "There was an error: " + response);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LocationsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Network not available");
    }
}
```

**So basically I would like to know if there is a standardized way to load more map markers from server with limit and offset like in recyclerview.**

Comment: You could use GeoFire and adjust/expand query radius (centered on user location) as required.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the reply Andy. This is one of the options that can work, but I am more interested in finding if there is some best practice or a standard that I can fallow, without using libraries.

Comment: In my estimation, a similar approach to the recyclerview cited would be to use the screen projection latlng bounds and on camera idle (stopped scrolling) requery - so the user is dictating what is queried by area of map displayed.  This has its own set of challenges though - e.g. how does zoom affect limit.

Comment: @Andy My original idea was to do this using camera moves, with something like `TouchableWrapper`, and load more `onCameraMoveCanceled`, but it seems hacky... One other solution that comes to mind (since I use the service to fill recyclerview fragment and the maps fragment) is to load markers on map only when the user scrolls to the bottom of my recyclerview, but it is not an ideal solution as well.